# Finding a Directed Graph from Image

Tags: image-processing, graph-theory, shortest-path

The problem that I'm facing is that I have an image. The image will contain shapes of triangle  , square and cross. Based on that i need to find a Directed Graph which connects the shapes together.

```
  If the shape is a square it means that it is directed to the next image (or node)
   in the direction of traversal

  if the shape is a triangle then it means it is connected to all nodes/shapes in the direction
  the vertices are pointing to.

  if the shape is a square then it means that it is connected all the nodes/shapes pointed out by its sides.
```

Example:[image]
My problem statement is to find the shortest path of traversal based upon these shapes.

Please help . Thanks in Advance.!!

Comment: Have you tried Dijkstras algorithm? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: yes.i am planning to implement it with Dijkstra's Algorithm.

Comment: only problem is that the adjacency matrix that i get involved many directed paths.So now i am thinking of optimizing the graph.So as to increase the program efficiency.Any inputs for that?